# Is a dictionary the right data structure for this?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, label

I would like to use a data structure that would allow me to store my data like this:

```
data[1][a]
data[1][b]
data[1][c]
data[1][d]
data[2][a]
data[2][b]
```

...
With the labels a, b, c, d known from the beginning, while  i iter over the 1, 2, ... from a list.

I thought about using a dictionary:

```
dict={} #How to initialize the dictionary ?

mylist=(1, 2, ...)
for i in mylist:
    dict[i][a]=something
    dict[i][b]=something_else
    etc
```

1) Is it the best data structure to use ? Else what would you use ?
2) If using the dictionary structure how to initialize the dictionary with the labels a, b, c & d ?

Comment: are `a,b,c` variables or labels, will it be `data[1][1]` or `data[1]['foo']`?

Comment: If you want to use a dict of dicts, you can use `d = {i: {} for i in mylist}` to initialize it.

Comment: @depperm They are labels, string fixed variables, like 'foo'.

Comment: @pschill Thank you, and how would you also initialize the a, b, c ?

Comment: @Arty What do you mean with _initialize the a, b, c?_ Just use the dict of dicts and insert the labels using the for loop from your question.

Comment: @pschill I don't understand how to initialize the other labels before adding the data in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have data[1][a] using dict. You could have a dict of dicts and initialize like so.

```
dict={}

mylist=(1, 2, 3)
labels = ('a','b','c','d')
something = 'foo'

for i in mylist:
    for l in labels:
        if(i in dict):
            dict[i].update({l:something})
        else:
            dict[i] = {l:something}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a list of dictionaries. And I suggest that you replace your suggested iteration:

```
for i in mylist:
    dict[i][a]=something
```

With this:

```
for elem in list_of_dicts:
    elem[a] = something
```

If for some reason, you really need the list index, you can do the following:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
    elem[a] = something # or list_of_dicts[i][a] = something
```

Regarding your question about initializing.

```
list_of_dicts = list()
list_of_dicts.append( { a : b, c : d } )
list_of_dicts.append( { e : f, g : h } )
```